# No http handler was found for request type 'GET' when I open chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

this is my web config page, I tried to look for answers in the internet but nothing helped me please some one help me.
the bug happening me when i tried to open a page with chart

```
 <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
        <add key="MyWebService.webserviceGeneral" value="http://loveburn.com/school/webserviceGeneral.asmx"/>
        <add key="ElectricWSL.WebService" value="http://localhost:62587/WebService.asmx"/>
        <add key="IsraelCities.WebServiceCities" value="http://www.loveburn.com/school/WebServiceCities.asmx"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpHandlers>
          <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
     type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, 
    System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
        <webServices>
          <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
          </protocols>
        </webServices>
  </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
         <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
     </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Which version of IIS ? You might need to configure the HTTP handlers in the `system.webserver` section

Comment: how i can see what is my version of ISS and when i tried to configure the HTTP handlers in the system.webserver section this is made me bug

Comment: Use Google to learn IIS or IIS Express, and there are tons you need to get started. In your case, you'd better use classic pipeline mode for the application pool, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis

Comment: some one help me ?